# Who pushed changes to origin in GIT

Tags: git

Our project has recently moved to GIT. Im liking the local commits a lot! It has caused some confusion in our team though and some things have been pushed which should not have been pushed. Consider this scenario

- dev 1 and dev 2 working on branch A and are committing
- dev 3 checks out branch A and then pushes changes to branch B (miraculously no conflicts)

All the checking will have dev1 and dev2 commit in. I cannot see a way of knowing that dev3 did the push to branch B.

Is there a way? Or am I misunderstanding the log when Im looking at these files.

From my understanding you push commits so that is why I am seeing dev1 and dev2 names. I would like to know who did the push though as well. The scenario above is a simplified version of what I think happened but hopefully is enough to get my point across.

Thanks

Comment: Excuse me to disturb you, when i make 'git log', I've the commit number, after, if it's a merge action, i've the merge detail, and after i have the author, and finally the date. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History ... Does this info are what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, who updated a ref is recorded in normal circumstances.  Depending on how your repository is hosted though, you may have other choices such as using a [post-receive](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive) hook script to record the ref updates and who made them.  IIRC, [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/) had an audit facility for doing this too, but I'm not sure if it still does or not.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Im surprised this isnt standard but I'll look for other things.